# PyCharm: customize output on run command

Tags: pycharm

When I run a script in PyCharm I get the following output:

[image: output]

Is there any way to remove the line 1 and line 3 and display only the printed output `Hello World`? I have a code demo and it would make my output look much cleaner.

I've tried entering "Presentation Mode" but I'm still getting the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering output using the Grep Console plugin. Alternatively, you could use Grep Console to highlight the lines you want your audience to see, dim the lines you want them to ignore.